# StateFlow collectAsState is not updating his value jetpack compose navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am making simple navigation app in jetpack compose. I am changing the screen using compose navigation, using some simple condition but my `destination` value is always same what I have initialise. I don't understand why this value is always same as `ScreenOne`. If you check the function `navigateToScreen` in viewmodel, if condition is true but `destination` value is not changing.

**FunAppNavigation**

```
@Composable
fun FunAppNavigation(
    viewModel: FunAppViewModel = koinViewModel(),
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
) {
    val destination = viewModel.navigationHandler.destination.collectAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.navigateToScreen()
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = destination) {
        navController.navigate(destination.value.route)
    }

     SideEffect {
        println(">> destination Value $destination")
     }

}
```

**FunAppViewModel**

```
class FunAppViewModel(
    val navigationHandler: NavigationHandler,
) : BaseViewModel() {

    fun navigateToScreen() {
        val destination = if (true) {
            DeviceRoutes.ScreenTwo
        } else {
            DeviceRoutes.ScreenOne
        }
        navigationHandler.navigate(destination)
    }
}
```

**NavigationHandler**

```
interface NavigationHandler {
    val destination: StateFlow<DeviceRoutes>
    fun navigate(deviceRoutes: DeviceRoutes)
}
```

**Navigator**

```
class Navigator : NavigationHandler {
    private val _destination: MutableStateFlow<DeviceRoutes> =
        MutableStateFlow(DeviceRoutes.ScreenOne)

    override val destination: StateFlow<DeviceRoutes> = _destination

    override fun navigate(deviceRoutes: DeviceRoutes) {
        _destination.value = deviceRoutes
    }
}
```

**DeviceRoutes**

```
sealed class DeviceRoutes(val route: String) {
    object ScreenOne : DeviceRoutes("ScreenOne")
    object ScreenTwo : DeviceRoutes("ScreenTwo")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you forgot to put `.value` inside the key of LaunchedEffect. So it will compare the reference of your `state` variable (which is the same) instead of comparing the content of your state which is your destination.

try in this way:

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = destination.value) {
    navController.navigate(destination.value.route)
}
```